# Status override bulk update

Tags: civimember

Is there anyway of turning off status override for all memberships rather than individually going into each one.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to clarify why you have so many with Status override? I know it isn't part of the 'answer' but I for one am curious.

Comment: Actually what I would like to do is status override everyone who pays by direct debit, so there membership stays current.

In relation to this question. We were using status override, not thinking that it stays that way constantly. We have now manually turned them off.

Comment: sounds like a simple extension would be able to deliver this but don't have a recipe to offer off-hand

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the civicrm database and, using PHPMyAdmin, find the table "civicrm_membership" and the column "is_overide", you could carefully change the relevant values to "NULL".  You would be advised to first take a backup of the database in case anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are wanting to have Memberships auto-renew based on  Direct Debit - this could be possible if there is an integration for the Direct Debit

Otherwise there may be a work around such as making Direct Debit memberships a type that is set to Lifetime, and you would then need to pick up on when a Direct Debit payment does not happen and put in an End Date.